# Why can't I use different LlamaIndex chat engine modes without an OpenAI key?

Tags: openai-api, llama, llama-index

I'm trying to perform initaial setup of a chatbot with some sample data to test everything is working before I start experimenting. whenever I try to change the chat mode of the chat engine, an error occurs because of a lack of an openAI API key.

I don't want to have to use openAI and am using llamaIndex as my LLM and a local embedding model to avoid using it. I'm just wodnering if theres a specific reason I can't use alternate chat modes or am I doing something wrong?

The following code runs completely fine

```
query_engine = vector_index.as_chat_engine()
response = query_engine.chat(prompt)
print(response)
```

but just changing it to this suddenly makes it need access to the open AI api.

```
query_engine = vector_index.as_chat_engine(chat_mode="context")
response = query_engine.chat(prompt)
print(response)
```